# Get smallest value for unique coordinate pair

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I will need a helping hand on my code please.

I have a matrix `A` [53x3] where my first two columns are the respective coordinates X and Y of the points and the third represents a weight. In this matrix, some lines are present in doublet (or triplet) and differ only in the third column (X and Y identical).
I want to create a matrix `B` with only the single and the line with the lowest weight.

At the level of the algo, I have the idea to do this via the loops for and if, keeping in memory how many lines are the same and after going directly to the different lines. That is, I want my code to read the matrix, then it takes the first line it compares to the second. If they are different from the line written in matrix B. If they are identical then look at the third line. If the third is different, it has taken the weights and compared them and entered the line, the weight is the smallest in the matrix `B`. (and that for the whole matrix).

```
lengthA = size(A);

for i = 1:lengthA(1)-1
    for j = i+1:lengthA(1)

        if (ismember(A(i,1),A(j,1))) && (ismember(A(i,2),A(j,2)))
            M = [A(i,3) A(j,3)];
            m = min(M);
            Res(i,:) = A(m,:);
        else
            Res(i,j) = A;
        end

    end
end
```

I tried this code but isn't working

Comment: You should make an attempt, post it, and ask specific questions.

Comment: I'm trying with a code like this

<code> lengthA=size(A);

for i=1:lengthA(1)-1
    for j=i+1:lengthA(1)
        
        if (ismember(A(i,1),A(j,1))) && (ismember(A(i,2),A(j,2)))
          M= [A(i,3) A(j,3)];
          m=min(M);
          Res(i,:)=A(m,:);
%         else 
%           Res(i,j)=A;
        end       
    end
end </code>

Comment: Edit your question if you can and format the code.  No one can read your comment.  If your matrix contains floating point values you'll need to be careful how you decide if they are "the same".

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accumarray` and `@min` to get the smallest value

```
[uA, ~, ind] = unique(A(:,1:2), 'rows', 'stable');
B = [uA accumarray(ind, A(:,3), [], @min)];
```

---

Update:

Here is a variant if you only want to use `for` and `if`. I use the variable `coordToCheck` to avoid rechecking a coordinate pair.

```
N = size(A,1);
coordToCheck = true(N,1);
Res = [];

for i = 1:N
    if coordToCheck(i)
        minVal = A(i,3);
        for j = i+1:N
            if coordToCheck(j)
                if isequal(A(i,[1 2]), A(j,[1 2]))
                    coordToCheck(j) = false;
                    % Update min value
                    minVal = min(minVal, A(j,3));
                end
            end
        end
        % Add corrdinates and min value
        Res(end+1,:) = [A(i,[1 2]), minVal];
    end
end
```

Comment: Thinks, it's working! I didn't know the function accumarray

Comment: Hello, Is it possible to do something similar but through one or more for-loops and if-loops ? (Even if this leads to a longer calculation time)

Comment: @Mac. Do you mean doing the same as above but using only for-loops and if-loops? Or do you have another, more complex, `A`matrix, with more columns to sort on?

Comment: @NLindors Yes I mean doing the same as above but using  for-loops and if-loops

Comment: @Mac. Ok, I've updated the answer with a such a variant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortrows` for the weight, and `unique` over the first 2 columns, for example:

```
[As, is] = sortrows(A);
[Au, iu] = unique(As(:,1:2), 'rows', 'first');
B = A(sort(is(iu)), :);
```

The last `sort` is just to preserve the order of the original tuples.

Comment: I do not know if you received a notification when I answered in the previous answer (I do not know yet how well the forum works) but in case it is not, I ask if is it possible to do something similar as above but through one or more for-loops and if-loops ? (Even if this leads to a longer calculation time). If you ever have an idea ^^